# Array, Game of Ognib

Tags: java, arrays

I needed to write a program that : simulate a 2-player game called Ognib.  In Ognib, each player is given a 5x5 grid where they place numbered tokens face up.  The tokens are numbered with an integer ranging from 1 to 100 inclusively, are all distinct and are sorted in increasing order.  Players cannot see their opponent’s grid – only their own.  One at a time, each player “calls” an integer and if any player has this token on their grid, they turn the token face down on their grid.  The goal of the game is for a player to have all tokens in a row, or in a column or in any of the 2 diagonals facing down before the opponent does.
With a 1-D array.

I have some problems in my program, 
First of all I don't know how to use two classes for one program, in fact my program in compacted in one class and it is a little messy I think. 
Second, my condition of winning if the player has a diagonal of 0 isn't working... And I have no idea why... 
Third, there is a limit of round of game of 25 turn which is the length of the array but I don't know how to change this...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ognib {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
          final int ROWS = 5;
          final int COLUMNS = 5;
          final int LENGTH = ROWS*COLUMNS;
          final int MIN_VALUE = 1; // represents the minimum value in the board
          final int MAX_VALUE = 100; // represents the maximun value in the board
          int number = 0; 
          int[] board1 = new int[LENGTH]; // represents the board as a 1-D array

          Random rand = new Random();
          int randomNumber = 0;    // an integer to be chosen at random
          boolean isDuplicate; // to indicate is randomNumber has already been picked or not

          // for every cell i in the board
          for (int i = 0; i < board1.length; ++i)
          {
                do
                {     // Generate a random number between MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE inclusive
                      randomNumber = rand.nextInt((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + 1) + MIN_VALUE;

                      isDuplicate = false; // initialy, let's assume this is not a duplicate

                      // check if this random value has already been inserted in the array in a previous cell
                      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                            if (board1[j] == randomNumber) {
                                  isDuplicate = true;
                  }
            }
                }
                while (isDuplicate); // pick a new random number until we pick a non-duplicate
                board1[i] = randomNumber;  // this random number is not a duplicate, assign it to the ith cell
          }
          int indexOfMin; 
          int temp; // for every element (except the last)           
          for (int index = 0; index < board1.length-1; index++)  {   
             indexOfMin = index;    // find the index of the smallest element between index and the last    
             for (int scan = index+1; scan < board1.length; scan++)      
                 if (board1[scan] < board1[indexOfMin])         
                 indexOfMin = scan;      // Swap the smallest element with the one at position ‘index’     
             temp = board1[indexOfMin];     
             board1[indexOfMin] = board1[index];    
             board1[index] = temp; }      

          int[] board2 = new int[LENGTH];
          for (int i = 0; i < board2.length; ++i)
          {
                do
                {     // Generate a random number between MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE inclusive
                      randomNumber = rand.nextInt((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + 1) + MIN_VALUE;

                      isDuplicate = false; // initialy, let's assume this is not a duplicate

                      // check if this random value has already been inserted in the array in a previous cell
                      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                            if (board2[j] == randomNumber) {
                                  isDuplicate = true;
                  }
            }
                }
                while (isDuplicate); // pick a new random number until we pick a non-duplicate
                board2[i] = randomNumber;  // this random number is not a duplicate, assign it to the ith cell
          }
          for (int index = 0; index < board2.length-1; index++)  {   
              indexOfMin = index;    // find the index of the smallest element between index and the last    
              for (int scan = index+1; scan < board2.length; scan++)      
                  if (board2[scan] < board2[indexOfMin])         
                  indexOfMin = scan;      // Swap the smallest element with the one at position ‘index’     
              temp = board2[indexOfMin];     
              board2[indexOfMin] = board2[index];    
              board2[index] = temp; }  

          boolean win; 
          // the array now contains all unique random values
          System.out.print("Enter your name: "); 
          String name = keyboard.next(); 

       do  
       {
          win=false; 
          System.out.println("Player Name: " + name); 
          System.out.println("=====================================================================================================");
          for (int h = 0; h < board1.length && h < board2.length; ++h) {
                if ( (h % 5)==0 && (h != 0) )  
                System.out.println ("|"); 
                System.out.print ("|"); 
                System.out.print("        "+ board1[h] + "        ");}
          System.out.println("|"); 
          System.out.print("=====================================================================================================");
          System.out.println(); 
          for ( int e = 1 ; e<=3 ; e++) {
                randomNumber = rand.nextInt((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + 1) + MIN_VALUE ;
                System.out.println ("Computer's Value: " + randomNumber); 
            for (int k = 0; k < board1.length && k < board2.length; ++k){
                if (board1[k] == randomNumber)
                    board1[k] = 0;
                if (board2[k] == randomNumber)
                    board2[k] = 0; }
                }
          for (int f=1 ; f<=1 ; f++){
            System.out.print (name + "'s Value: ");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < board1.length && j < board2.length; ++j){
                if (board1[j]== number )
                    board1[j] = 0; 
                if ( board2[j] == number)
                    board2[j] = 0; }
            System.out.println(); }
            if ((board1[1]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[25]==0) ||
                (board1[5]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[21]==0) ||
                (board2[1]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[25]==0) ||
                (board2[5]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[21]==0)){
                System.out.println("Diagonal win detected...");
                win=true; 
                break; }
            if (board1[1]==0 && board1[6]==0 && board1[11]==0 && board1[16]==0 && board1[21]==0 || 
                board1[2]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[12]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[22]==0 ||
                board1[3]==0 && board1[8]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[18]==0 && board1[23]==0 ||
                board1[4]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[14]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[24]==0 ||
                board1[5]==0 && board1[10]==0 && board1[15]==0 && board1[20]==0 && board1[25]==0||
                board2[1]==0 && board2[6]==0 && board2[11]==0 && board2[16]==0 && board2[21]==0 || 
                board2[2]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[12]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[22]==0 ||
                board2[3]==0 && board2[8]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[18]==0 && board2[23]==0 ||
                board2[4]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[14]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[24]==0 ||
                board2[5]==0 && board2[10]==0 && board2[15]==0 && board2[20]==0 && board2[25]==0 ){
                System.out.println("Colum win detected...");
                win = true;
                break;}
            if (board1[1]==0 && board1[2]==0 && board1[3]==0 && board1[4]==0 && board1[5]==0 || 
                board1[6]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[8]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[10]==0 ||
                board1[11]==0 && board1[12]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[14]==0 && board1[15]==0 ||
                board1[16]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[18]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[20]==0 ||
                board1[21]==0 && board1[22]==0 && board1[23]==0 && board1[24]==0 && board1[25]==0||
                board2[1]==0 && board2[2]==0 && board2[3]==0 && board2[4]==0 && board2[5]==0 || 
                board2[6]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[8]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[10]==0 ||
                board2[11]==0 && board2[12]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[14]==0 && board2[15]==0 ||
                board2[16]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[18]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[20]==0 ||
                board2[21]==0 && board2[22]==0 && board2[23]==0 && board2[24]==0 && board2[25]==0){
                System.out.println("Row win detected...");
                win=true; 
                break; }
            }
       while (!win); 

       if (win=true)
        System.out.println("===Final Results==="); 
        System.out.println("Player Name: " + name); 
        for (int h = 0; h < board1.length; ++h) {
            if ( (h % 5)==0 && (h != 0) )  
            System.out.println ("|"); 
            System.out.print ("|"); 
            System.out.print("        "+ board1[h] + "        "); }
        System.out.println(); 
        if (board1[1]==0 && board1[6]==0 && board1[11]==0 && board1[16]==0 && board1[21]==0 || 
            board1[2]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[12]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[22]==0 ||
            board1[3]==0 && board1[8]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[18]==0 && board1[23]==0 ||
            board1[4]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[14]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[24]==0 ||
            board1[5]==0 && board1[10]==0 && board1[15]==0 && board1[20]==0 && board1[25]==0|| 
            board1[1]==0 && board1[2]==0 && board1[3]==0 && board1[4]==0 && board1[5]==0 || 
            board1[6]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[8]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[10]==0 ||
            board1[11]==0 && board1[12]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[14]==0 && board1[15]==0 ||
            board1[16]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[18]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[20]==0 ||
            board1[21]==0 && board1[22]==0 && board1[23]==0 && board1[24]==0 && board1[25]==0||
            board1[1]==0 && board1[7]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[19]==0 && board1[25]==0 ||
            board1[5]==0 && board1[9]==0 && board1[13]==0 && board1[17]==0 && board1[21]==0){
            System.out.println(name + "has a winning card!");
            System.out.println();}
        System.out.println("Player Name: Computer"); 
        for (int h = 0; h < board2.length; ++h) {
            if ( (h % 5)==0 && (h != 0) )  
            System.out.println ("|"); 
            System.out.print ("|"); 
            System.out.print("        "+ board2[h] + "        "); }
        System.out.println(); 
        if (board2[1]==0 && board2[6]==0 && board2[11]==0 && board2[16]==0 && board2[21]==0 || 
            board2[2]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[12]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[22]==0 ||
            board2[3]==0 && board2[8]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[18]==0 && board2[23]==0 ||
            board2[4]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[14]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[24]==0 ||
            board2[5]==0 && board2[10]==0 && board2[15]==0 && board2[20]==0 && board2[25]==0||
            board2[1]==0 && board2[2]==0 && board2[3]==0 && board2[4]==0 && board2[5]==0 || 
            board2[6]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[8]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[10]==0 ||
            board2[11]==0 && board2[12]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[14]==0 && board2[15]==0 ||
            board2[16]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[18]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[20]==0 ||
            board2[21]==0 && board2[22]==0 && board2[23]==0 && board2[24]==0 && board2[25]==0 ||
            board2[1]==0 && board2[7]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[19]==0 && board2[25]==0 ||
            board2[5]==0 && board2[9]==0 && board2[13]==0 && board2[17]==0 && board2[21]==0) {
            System.out.println("Computer has a winning card!"); }
        }

    }
```

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of your array starts from 0. So wherever you have your indexes written in the program decrease each one by 1 . Array index starts from 0 not 1. Replace every index by reducing each one by 1 and it should work fine. Let me know ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Index should start at `0`, not `1`.